# Netty channel write and flush not writing message

Tags: java, netty

I am trying to write byte array to the ctx in netty using the below way however I am not able to. I am using ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.

```
   ByteBuf mbuf = ctx.alloc().buffer();
   mbuf.setByte(0, 69);
   mbuf.setByte(1, 70);
   mbuf.setByte(2, 71);
   ctx.writeAndFlush(mbuf);
```

In the logs it shows below:

Nov 28, 2017 7:52:16 PM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler write
INFO: [id: 0x391dced5, L:/127.0.0.1:3978 - R:/127.0.0.1:52306] WRITE: 0B

Am I missing something here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your buffer is considered "empty" because its writerIndex is not changed when you use the `setByte` method. Use `writeByte` or other `writeXXX` methods instead. These advance the writerIndex, which means Netty is able to see that something has actually been written to the buffer.